# Facebook game sound in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, audio, soundmanager2

I am looking for a working way to play sound in facebook HTML5 games.

HTML5 audio is pretty buggy right now and has too many problems to use it in my game.
I tried a sound kit : SoundManager2 which uses flash (http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) but it is not working inside facebook because of iframes...

Is there any way to have properly working sounds on an HTML5 game ? Or if anyone knows a way to make soundmanager work inside facebook